# Conditionally expose port in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, debugging, dockerfile

I'm trying to expose debug port inside Dockerfile based on a build argument(DEBUG_ENABLED). This image goes into a k8s pod eventually on a cluster with multiple pods running for various apps. I'm trying to EXPOSE ports in all the images based on a build-arg.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
ARG DEBUG_ENABLED=true
:
:
EXPOSE 8080
RUN if [ "$DEBUG_ENABLED" = "true" ] ; \
      then EXPOSE 8000 ; \
    else echo "debug is set to false"; \
    fi 
ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I know the "EXPOSE" statement will not work in the `RUN if...` construct. But is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? EXPOSE statement does not affect the accessibility of the port, if the port is open, you can access it even if it is not exposed using EXPOSE.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Do you mean I should be able to attach my debugger to this container running inside k8s pod from my IDE even if the docker image was built without this EXPOSE 8000. ?

Comment: Yes, using the container IP, you can attach. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: EXPOSE does so little that I'd just unconditionally leave it in if you think it's meaningful sometimes.

Comment: "EXPOSE statement does not affect the accessibility of the port," -- ?? So what does it do?

Comment: Never mind, i got the answer from here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose -- The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.

Answer (score 0):

I also looking for the solution.

I known `EXPOSE` just some kind of docs for image.
but I think it's really useful.

### directly NO

seems the answer is `NO` for now.

SO I have to create 2 (or more) `dockerfile` for that purpose.

### workaround

maybe build from STDIN (generate dockerfile by other program)
can be a workaround.

But it's really not that straightforward and effective

// It is no different from dynamically creating a dockerfile.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#pipe-dockerfile-through-stdin

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/#text-files

[https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement:~:text=Dockerfile through STDIN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement:~:text=Dockerfile%20through%20STDIN%20(-,docker%20build%20%2D,-%3C%20somefile)%2C%20there%20is)